# build Qualcomm's FastCV sample

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, fastcv

I try to build the [Qualcomm's FastCV](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv) sample fastcorner. I add the project file into Eclipse, and follow the [instruction](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/compiling-and-running-fastcv-sample-app) to "add C/C++ attributes to the project" using "Convert to a C++ Project". I got nothing in the

[image: wizard]

I try to clean the project, got follow errors:

```
**** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project FastCVSample ****

make clean 
Host OS was auto-detected: windows
gawk.exe": fatal: can't open source file "/cygdrive/d/Android/android-ndk-r7/build/awk/check-awk.awk" for reading (No such file or directory)
/cygdrive/d/Android/android-ndk-r7/build/core/init.mk:258: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !    
make: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/Android/fastcv-android-1-0-3/samples/fastcorner'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/Android/fastcv-android-1-0-3/samples/fastcorner'
Makefile:57: recipe for target `clean' failed

**** Build Finished ****
```

It seems eclipse can not find "awk", but I can successfully execute awk in cygwin, and I also set the C/C++ build envirement variable in "HOST_AWK" in eclipse, nothing helps.

Is there anyone know what should I do?

Comment: @ingsaurabh, no, seems nothing on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on ndk-r7 and I had to rename ndk/prebuild/windows/bin/awk.exe to _awk.exe.

In ndk-r7b I don't have this issue.